# Root Solver Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

[image: Equation in question]

I have an equation that I want to graph with ay being the x-axis and ax being the y-axis. The basis is that I have values for everything apart from ax so I researched online for root solving and I stumbled on a video and followed it and I got the code underneath. The video is by HagesLab on YouTube titled "Root finding in python" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=768JiuFlBhc&list=LL&index=4&ab_channel=HagesLab

For context I am trying to make a g-g diagram for a lap time simulator using motorcycles in mind.

I have written out a piece of code and I am wondering if I have written it correctly as it isn't what I believe it should look like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def fxn1(ax,w,m,Fd,ay,g,b,h,ha,ux,uy):
    return (((w*((m*ax)+Fd)*np.sqrt((ay**2)+(g**2)))/(g*((w-b)*m*np.sqrt((ay**2)+(g**2))+(m*ax*h)+(Fd*ha))))**2 * 1/(ux**2)) + ((ay/g)**2 * 1/(uy**2)) - 1

Tlist = np.linspace(0,1.44,num = 1000)

plt.figure(num=2, dpi=120)
plt.plot(Tlist,fxn1(Tlist,1.5,250,48,1.44*9.81,9.81,0.73,0.69,0.69,1.2,1.44),label="Lateral Accel")
plt.show()
```

[image: Diagram in question]

It should look like the 20m/s section between ax (Just below 0 and above)

My entire code looks like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = 9.81  # Gravity
pa = 1.2  # Air density
m = 250  # mass of bike
h = 0.69  # centre of mass height
ha = 0.69  # height of centre pressure
w = 1.5  # wheelbase
b = 0.73  # longitudinal distance of centre of mass
CdA = 0.2  # drag coefficient
PMax = 180000  # max power
ux = 1.2  # Longitudinal friction coefficient
uy = 1.44  # Lateral friction coefficient

V = 20 # Base Velocity

Fd = 0.5 * pa * CdA * V**2  # Drag Force 48 @ 20m/s

Ap = ((PMax / (m * V)) - (Fd / m)) / g  # 3.65g is max acceleration @ 20m/s (No Lateral Force)

yw = np.linspace(-1.44, 1.44, 100) # Establishing Ay boundaries
Aw = (((b * np.sqrt((yw * g)**2 + g**2)) / h) - ((Fd * ha) / (m * h))) / g # Wheelie Condition

Wheelie_Min = np.minimum(Ap, Aw) # Minimum of power limited and tyre limited conditions in acceleration

Ad = (((g * ux * (np.sqrt(1 - (((yw * g)/ g)**2) * (1 / uy**2))) + (Fd / m))) * -1) / g # Deceleration

As = (((w-b) * np.sqrt((yw * g)**2 + g**2)) / h - ((Fd * ha) / (m *h))) / (g * -1) # Stoppie Condition

Deceleration_Max = np.maximum(Ad, As) # Maximum between braking and stoppie conditions

plt.plot(yw, Deceleration_Max, 'r')
plt.plot(yw, Wheelie_Min, 'r')
plt.show()
```

And it shows this
[image]

So clearly what is left is the connection between positive and negative parts

Comment: Please cite the video or code you're referencing?

Comment: I have edited the post and I have cited the video

Comment: That code just gives me a single upward curve.

Comment: What does inputting 80 directly into your function give you?

Comment: What do you mean inputting 80 into the function? Sorry I am relatively new to this

Comment: @KarlBurnett Setting V = 80 m/s and getting a list of the points for all of the time steps.

Comment: @SolomonUcko I just changed it to 80 and it looks like the 80 in the paper but the bottom bit looks too sharp, I edited the post so that it has all the code that I have in it

Comment: I see, that helps me understand your question better. Would something like `plt.plot(output, input, 'r')` be useful?

Comment: What does the 'r' do for the plot?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html says it means red.